# Python how to do commands in python that enter's in command panel

Tags: python, shell, cmd, sendkeys, os.system

I need to access command prompt in python, currently I use

```
import win32com.client
from datetime import datetime
import time


datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
def start():
    datestring = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')

    shell.run("cmd")
    shell.AppActivate("cmd")
    time.sleep(2)
    shell.SendKeys('ffmpeg -y -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Webcam C270"  kamera'+datestring+'.mp4')
    time.sleep(1)
    shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")


def stop():
    time.sleep(2)

    shell.SendKeys('^c')
    time.sleep(2)
    shell.SendKeys('exit')
    time.sleep(1)
    shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}")
```

I would need to get os.system commands like `os.system(start cmd)` and other commands for writing inside of cmd(command panel).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the command prompt, and running programs from there, you can just immediately run the programs that you are interested in. Take a look at python's [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

So in your case,

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'ffmpeg -y -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Webcam C270"  kamera'+datestring+'.mp4'
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
```

If you want to start/stop on demand, then you can do this:

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

cmd = 'ffmpeg -y -f dshow -i video="Logitech HD Webcam C270"  kamera'+datestring+'.mp4'
pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                   shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid) 

os.killpg(os.getpgid(pro.pid), signal.SIGTERM)  # Send the signal to all the process groups
```

`subprocess.Popen` starts the process, and `os.killpg` will stop it.

By the way, it's *"Command Prompt"*, not "Command Panel". I'm not being pedantic here - unless the context gives it away, many people will have no clue what "Command Panel" is referring to.

Comment: Hey! I must admit your choice is much simpler and all, but i need a program that starts recording by command, and stop's by command. That's why i choose cmd, so i could tell it when to stop.

Comment: @J.Foe I augmented my answer.

Comment: It shows me this error:                                                                 
` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Dobot Magician/Audio_python/Py3.6/Call_and_check/record_test.py", line 8, in <module>
    shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'setsid'

Process finished with exit code 1`

Comment: @J.Foe Ah crap that's right... os.setsid is only available on Unix. :/ I'm looking into an alternative.

Comment: Is there any way I could change/replace `os.setsid`, the second you answered that is for linux only, i was searching for replacement but I didn't get any luck.